# Get lat/lng of points along the route say after every 100m

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using Direction Service I have drawn a route on the map.
Now i wish to save this route as a polygon in MySQL

So I need to get the lat/lng of points on the route say after each 100 meters which i will save as a polygon.
How can i do it in Google Map V3. Im using JS and JAVA.

I also found similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216384/how-to-get-entire-latlng-along-a-route-google-api-v3) with 75+ views but without any replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first I would focus on the

> getPath()

method of the polyline object in Google Maps API v3.

[See this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polyline)

This will return an MVC Array of LatLng objects, which are the vertices of the generated route polyline.
Then if you want more point samples (by which I mean you want to have points after every 100 meters for example), you can write a loop to generate more points.
What is going to happen in the loop is that it gets the LatLng with the current index and gets the next one. Then it calculates the heading between them and then if the distance between the two points examined is more than 100 meters, then it would place a point at 100 meters of distance from the current indexed point.

To give you more food of thought for this I suggest you take a look at [this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical)

During the loop you would collect the latlngs into a new array, which would at the end of the loop, contain all your desired vertices of the generated polyline.

As for storing these points in mysql, you have to format these points into WKT format.
Since storing a directions polyline as polygon is nonsense, I recommend you using LINESTRING.
Here is a wikipedia page that gives you an overview of what WKT is: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text)

Comment: Ok thanks for such a precise reply.
getPath() will return me mvc array. I know how can i get what i req. from that array. Now just tell me last things:
I have the response object with me in   directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
how do i get the polyline object from response object so as to invoke getPath() on it.

Comment: i have found something but not sure.
is overview_path is wat im looking for ?

Comment: In the doc https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#DirectionsResponseElements it says overview_polyline but i have been working with overview_path before, so its a yes from me :)

Comment: i have drawn the route, successfully saved it as polygon too,now just one thing is remaining, after drawing the route if user modifies it by dragging the points how can i use overview_path on this modified route ? I have searched for routes events but didnt found any.
I have found directions_changed event.I just somehow want the reference to the new changed route. How can i get this reference ?

Comment: in directions_changed event, put in e into the callback function and write it to console first, to explore what is in there.

Comment: Example: google.maps.addListener(polyline, "directions_changed", function(e){console.log(e);});